# kendo ui grid cell display area shrinks as more data is added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datagrid, kendo-ui

How do I prevent tell the grid to maximize record display area and keep the area for page controls fixed?  This is what I am experiencing when data is being added to the grid. The record display area shrinks, page navigation control area keeps increasing as more pages are added, taking up the remaining space, while page navigation controls are vertically aligned instead of horizontally aligned.

This started happening after upgrading to version 2012.3.1114 of Kendo UI Web.[image]

**EDITING WITH MORE INFO:**

I am initializing the grid as follows:

```
    $("#kendoGrid").kendoGrid({         
        height: "200px",  div is constant height
        dataSource: this._dataSource,
        autowidth: true,
        columns: columnModels,
        sortable: true,                             
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true
        },              
        width: '100%'

    });
```

and grid is part of an ASP.NET MVC page defined as follows:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>

        <div id="centerstage"  >
            <div id="left" >
                <div id="accordion">                                       
                </div>              
            </div>  
            <div id="main-content-div" style="overflow: hidden">
                <div id="center" class="column" />                   
                <div id="console" class="console" >
                    <table  id="kendoGrid" >
                    </table>
                    <div id="pager"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right" >
                <div id="dashboardDiv"  >
                    <p>dash board</p>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

and initialized using the kendo splitter.

```
    $("#centerstage").kendoSplitter({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        panes: [
                        { collapsible: true, resizable: true, size: "21%" },
                        { collapsible: false, resizable: true, size: "60%" },
                        { collapsible: true, resizable: true, size: "19%" }
                    ]
    });

    $("#main-content-div").kendoSplitter({
        orientation: "vertical",
        panes: [
                        { collapsible: false, size: "500px" },
                        { collapsible: true, resizable: true, size: "220px" }
                    ]
    });
```

Comment: We need some code ... Try jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727400/kendoui-grid-pagination the pager display error looks the same between these 2 questions.